# Java - Google Drive API v3 - return specific fields for file - syntax

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I am trying to get a large junk of Drive Files. I need to get the 3 Parameters **emailAdress**, **displayName** and **modifiedTime**. I only want to **call the API once**, to reduce processing time. However I cant figure out the syntax for the combined fields.

```
files = getDriveService().files().list()
                .setFields("files, permissions(emailAddress,displayName)")
                .setIncludeTeamDriveItems(true)
                .setSupportsTeamDrives(true).execute();
```

Gives me:

```
"code": 400,
"errors": [
    {
        "domain": "global",
        "location": "fields",
        "locationType": "parameter",
        "message": "Invalid field selection permissions",
        "reason": "invalidParameter"
    }
],
"message": "Invalid field selection permissions"
```

I`ve tried:

```
.setFields("files, permissions(emailAddress,displayName)")

.setFields("files(modifiedTime), permissions(emailAddress,displayName)")

.setFields("files/modifiedTime, permissions(emailAddress,displayName)")

.setFields("modifiedTime, permissions(emailAddress,displayName)")

.setFields("permissions(emailAddress,displayName)")
.setFields("modifiedTime")
```

Is it even possible to setFields() in combination with

> .setSupportTeamDrives(true)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Permission](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions) refers to who can access a file. It is connected to a specific file.

Because of this, `permissions` is a field of the [File resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files), not a field in [Files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list#response_1) response, so it's normal that you're not getting the desired outcome. So you should access `permissions` as a field inside `files`. The request should be like this:

```
.setFields("files(modifiedTime, permissions(emailAddress, displayName))")
```

I hope this is of any help.